# Different form based on media query

Tags: forms, css, media-queries

I have a form with a huge list of options to choose. Depending on the screen size, I want to have different ways to display these options. If it's a large screen, I want to display them as regular list with a checkbox for each item. If it's a small screen, I want to have a single select-field. Is this possible? And - if yes - how?

Large Screen:

```
    <form>
     <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="1" checked="checked"/>Text</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="2"/>Text</li>
     </ul>
    </form>
```

Small Screen:

```
    <form>
     <select name="rating" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">Text</option>
      <option value="2" selected="selected">Text</option>
     </select>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way will be - to show/hide elements (select or ul) by mediaquery:

For example for low screen: {display:none;} - for ul, and {display:block;} - for select

Comment: Yes. But then there are still both in source-code. And if the user submits the form, always the values in the form for small screens (the last form) would be submitted.

Comment: that is not css problem. it's php problem. you can resolve it via JS. on choosing some of checboxes - changing the value of select! and when you choose some another option in select - changing the checkbox :) it's easy. ;) you can do it! i belive in you!

Answer (score 0):

From a UX perspective, it means that on a large screen, users can select more than one values (it being checkboxes), while on a smaller screen, they are only allowed 1 value.

From coding maintenance point of view, if you have two sets for form, it means you have two values to change for every option changed.

First, I guess would be to identify if its really want you want: users have more choices on larger screen and only one choice on a smaller screen.

Comment: You're right. I forgot to add "multiple" to the select.